# angular.js is it possible to filter using an expression

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have an expression which displays the $routeParams. Is it possible to pass this expression into a filter?

Currently I have:

```
<div class="services" ng-repeat="service in services | filter: { _id: '53bd9358dfc3d5d128930f53' }">
```

I would like the _id value to be dynamic and respond to the $routeParams which is working as {{id}} on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You can grab the url parameter and bind it to an object on the scope in the controller then use it as a filter.

When the url parameter changes, it will automatically filter due to angular's two way binding.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In html:
`<div class="services" ng-repeat="service in services | filter: json">`

In js:
`$scope.json={};json._id=$routeParams.id;`